# Can this animation be done with javascript?

Tags: javascript, animation

So, I need to make a simulation of processor scheduling and I thought JavaScript could do the trick until I found out that it doesn't support sleep (or similar method). It has setTimeout but it is really too much to figure out and synchronize all the elements).

In my animation I want to have ready queue, then process go to CPU where it waits until finished, then it goes to waiting queue where it uses memory, and then it is put back to ready queue. The thing is I want process in CPU and process in waiting queue to do their thing in same time (to be "busy"). 
If i put all processes in same jQuery queue animation then it is not possible. 
If I try to do it without jQuery queues then there is problem that one animation wont wait for previous to finish. And there is a problem where everything is calculated while loops are running so basically it set all the variable first and then runs the animation. 
And this is just too much of a work (if possible) to do with setTimeout functions.

So basically i want to know can a similar animation like this be done in JavaScript (and some library if easier): [this animation](http://courses.cs.vt.edu/csonline/OS/Lessons/Processes/index.html)

Or if not could you tell me some language and api where it could be easily done (preferably some fast to learn language).

Many tnx.

Comment: Why all the talk about CPU? It's just confusing.

Comment: Sry for confusion but I don't know how to explain it better. Anyway I need to make practically the same animation as in link that I've provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I've been working on couple of flash-like website that are using only javascript. This animation is very simple and you can use javascript for that with no problem.

I recommend [TweenMax](http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/) plugin.

Comment: If I would have only 1 process (small image in simulation) I could do it real easy. But if I have more I'm having troubles. Let me try to explain in pseudo code.
-
while (all processes are not finished) { // this is bool variable-
 take the last element of ready queue-
 animte it to the CPU-
 wait for some time-
 animate it to the waiting queue, and at the same time get another element from ready queue-
 process that's now in waiting queue, hold it for some time and take it back to ready queue
}

problem is JS continues to execute code not waiting animations to finish which messes my variables